# ThreadNumber in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using the function to get threadNum but, i see that it always gets me 1 though i have setup 5 threads. This is how i have my threads setup. I was expecting it to give me 1,2,3,4,5. Is my understanding right?

[image: threadSetup]

and this is what i see in log.

[image: threadNumber in log]

This is with one loop. I also tried with multiple loops and i see the same result.

Comment: `${__threadNum}` should work, how you call it?

Comment: i am using it in the http request like this ${__P(threadNum) which i think was the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the details on how you're "using" it it's hard to say what's wrong, I cannot reproduce it using the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(ctx.getThreadNum(),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

And thread numbers are zero-based so it will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

In the above example `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance, see JavaDoc and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information

Comment: i have tried to use in the request directly like: ${__P(threadNum).

Comment: Then you will get same property value for all threads (virtual users), if you haven't defined the property value - you will get default placeholder of `1` which seems to be exactly your case. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter Properties concept

Answer (score 0):

[__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) is a function not a property, so use it directly

```
${__threadNum}
```

> The thread number function simply returns the number of the thread currently being executed. These numbers are only locally unique with respect to their ThreadGroup